# jhipster using rest api and rest template with the same authentication

Tags: jhipster

I had generated a jhipster project using java (spring boot) and angular, I want to use angular for admin module it's management all content of the site and using angular in front-end and java in back-end. The home page uses rest template to display the content, I need using the same authentication between the admin module and the home page. when I login in admin module and then I back to the home page the name of login user will display in home page but I can't get the authentication of login user in home page

1. In rest api when getting login user I will use SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated() to check like below

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> getSalesProduct() {
    if (SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated()) {
        User user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get()).get();
    }
```

2. in rest template I also use SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated() to check but the result alway false

```
@GetMapping("/profile")
public ModelAndView profile() {
     if (SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated()) {             
         User user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get());
     }
```

Please give me some ideas how to get the authentication in home page.

Comment: thanks @GaëlMarziou i had edited my question, i used SecurityUtils of Jhipster generated for home page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The home page uses rest template to display the content". From your code extract using ModelAndView, I would guess that you use Spring MVC view template. Which template engine do you use? Thymeleaf, Freemarker ?

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou, I use Thymeleaf. I must get login user before and after that, I will fill data into Thymeleaf but I can't get user login information because of SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated() always false

Comment: OK, so 2 different frontend approaches. Which authentication type did you select in JHipster: JWT, session, ...?

Comment: thanks @GaëlMarziou, I use JWT authentication for my project

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that you are using 2 frontend technologies: Angular (admin single page application generated by JHipster) and Spring MVC with Thymeleaf which work completely differently.

The JWT authentication type that you selected in JHipster requires the frontend to provide the auth token via a HTTP header. In the generated angular app, upon authentication the token is stored by javascript code in browser LocalStorage and then token is added by angular app as a HTTP header to each request to backend.

When browser requests your Spring MVC home page, there's no javascript code to add the token to the request, so backend says that this is an anonymous request.

You could try one of these 2 alternatives:

- Write your home page as an Angular app and re-use some components and services from the generated admin part
- Re-generate your app with session authentication type as it uses a cookie for authentication which is automatically sent to backend by browser

Comment: thanks @Gaël Marziou i will move forward with your approach